# Read multiple files present in 2 folders

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have 7 vcf files present in 2 directories:
[dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsstz.png)

I want to concatenate all files present on both folders and then read them through python.
I am trying this code:

```
# Import Modules
import os
import pandas as pd
import vcf

# Folder Path
path1 = "C://Users//USER//Desktop//Anas/VCFs_1/"
path2 = "C://Users//USER//Desktop//Anas/VCFs_2/"
#os.chdir(path1)


def read(f1,f2):
    reader = vcf.Reader(open(f1,f2))
    df = pd.DataFrame([vars(r) for r in reader])
    out = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(df.INFO.tolist()),
                   left_index=True, right_index=True)
    return out
# Read text File


def read_text_file(file_path1,file_path2):
    with open(file_path1, 'r') as f:
        with open(file_path2,'r') as f:
            print(read(path1,path2))


# iterate through all file
for file in os.listdir():
    # Check whether file is in text format or not
    if file.endswith(".vcf"):
        file_path1 = f"{path1}\{file}"
        file_path2 = f"{path2}\{file}"
        print(file_path1,"\n\n",file_path2)

# call read text file function
#data = read_text_file(path1,path2)
print(read_text_file(path1,path2))
```

But its giving me permission error. I know when we try to read folders instead files then we get this error. But how can i read files present in folders? Any suggestion?

Comment: Are the files open by another program? That also give permission errors.

Comment: No i am trying to open files through this code

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run your Python code with Administrator privileges, if you are trying to access another user's files.

Comment: I have also tried to execute code with admin previloges but nothing happened. There is something wrong in code

Comment: A set of small issues in the code:

`os.listdir()` requires a path, maybe you need to run this twice. One for "path1" and "path2" in order to list all files on thats routes.

At the read function, you call open with two arguments, but it takes only one.
`open(f1,f2)`

But none of this things may conduct to permission error. Maybe it's a good idea to print all file found in order to debug if the complete url of a file es correct

Comment: I have changed my code and now its working :                                           # iterate through all file
for file1 in os.listdir(path1):
    # Check whether the file is in text format or not
    if file1.endswith(".vcf"):
        file_path1 = f"{path1}\{file1}"
        reader1 = vcf.Reader(open(file_path1))
        df1 = pd.DataFrame([vars(r) for r in reader1])
        out1 = df1.merge(pd.DataFrame(df1.INFO.tolist()),
                                 left_index=True, right_index=True)
        print(file_path1)